# Unix (NFS Error)- 7320 Storage

Tags: storage

I get the following errors on one of my servers:

```
NFS op OP_OPEN got error NFS4ERR_DELAY causing recovery action NR_DELAY
NFS op OP_WRITE got error NFS4ERR_STALE causing recovery action NR_STALE
NFS4 error: NFS4ERR_STALE
```

What kind of error is it? As it is not captured on my Alerts that anything strange is happening?

Comment: You should more information, e.g. what OS is your server running, what NFS configuration etc.